# When using 'gemspec' in a Gemfile how do I do the :require => 'foo'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

The gem has a few development dependencies like ruby-debug19 and sqlite3-ruby where the gem name and the require are different.  We handle this in the Gemfile by using the :require => 'foo' option.

e.g.

```
gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

We are trying to move all of these to the gemspec file and use the 'gemspec' directive in the Gemfile.

in the gemspec these become:

```
s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3-ruby"
s.add_development_dependency 'ruby-debug19'
```

Is there a way to provide that :require => option when using s.add_dependency ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't, you still need to override the value in the Gemfile.

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in .gemspec
gemspec
```

Small tip: if you use the `sqlite3` gem instead of `sqlite3-ruby` (which is actually the same), then you don't need to specify a different require.

Comment: Why is that?  Does add_development_dependency accomplish the same thing as :required => false?

Comment: So I guess if we want to `require: false` a development dependency, then we need to specify the gem in the gemspec first as a development dependency, then add it to the Gemfile as a development dependency and `require: false`?